# JDesktopPane and JInternalFrame help!

Tags: java, collections, jinternalframe, jlayeredpane, jdesktoppane

Greetings,

I have a question with regards to limiting duplicate JInternalFrames to a JDesktopPane.
Basically, adding an instance JInternalFrame to the JDesktopPane is comprehensive.
But limiting duplicate JInternalFrame of the same instance on the JDesktopPane and making that instance to the top layer of the JDesktopPane.

How could I implement this?
Am I going to store all instances to a ArrayList and check whether it's the instance about the execute is already opened?

You're reply is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Cyril H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * method to search for active internal frame windows
 * and return true or false depending on the outcome. this method uses internalframe names
 */
public boolean searchIFrame(String search, JInternalFrame frame[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < frame.length; i++)
        if(frame[i].getTitle().toString().equals(search))
            return true;
        return false;
}

//its implementation in your program. "Information Form" is the internalframe's name
//jdesk is the desktoppane object or instance
boolean srch = searchIFrame("Information Form", jdesk.getAllFrames());
    if(!srch) {        
                VisitationForm at = new VisitationForm();
                at.pack();
                jdesk.add(at);

                try
                {
                    at.setSelected(true);
                    at.setVisible(true);
                    // We're done, so clear the feedback message
                    //bar.setString(" ");
                    //bar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    at.requestFocus();

                }
                catch (PropertyVetoException pve)
                {
                    //bar.setString(" ");
                    //bar.setIndeterminate(false);

                    // Then display the error in a dialog box
                    System.out.println(pve);
                }

            }
```